# obtener últimos y penúltimos registros sql

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia tengo la tabla siguiente donde almacena clave de producto, numero de lista, proveedor, linea, precio y fecha lo que quiero comparar es de acuerdo al ultimo y penultimo numero de lista y fecha que son varios productos con lista 3 y 2 que serian los ultimos a simple vista, quiero saber si se da mas casos cuales son los productos con ultimo numero de lista y penultimo para comparar estos dos ultimos resultados y saber que cambios hubieron ejemplo si en la ultima lista hay productos nuevos o bien no estan, a mi se me ocurrio usar:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by CLAVE ORDER BY NOLIST) AS POS,* 
FROM  TABLA
WHERE PROV='0161' AND LIN='23'
```

pero no me funciona alguien puede ayudarme

```
    CLAVE              NOLIS PROV   LIN              PRECIO  FECHA
    C-7D2.0             1   0161    23              557.42  2020-03-04 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.0             2   0161    23              557.42  2020-03-04 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.0             3   0161    23              557.42  2020-03-05 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.2             1   0161    23              213.47  2020-03-04 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.2             2   0161    23              213.47  2020-03-04 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.2             3   0161    23              213.47  2020-03-05 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.4             1   0161    23              542.94  2020-03-04 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.4             2   0161    23              542.94  2020-03-04 00:00:00.000
    C-7D2.4             3   0161    23              542.94  2020-03-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Ya tienes el `ROW_NUMBER`, ahora debes agregar el filtro (`WHERE`) que quieres. Ah, y un hint, deberías ver de ordenar por `NOLIST` descendiente

Comment: ¿Y que problema has tenido?

Comment: el problema es que si en la lista 2 o numero de lista agregue el numero de producto 123 no me lo trae en mi consulta a la hora de traer los penultimos

Comment: sorry, no entiendo tu comentario. Puedes postear qué es lo que no está funcionando?